# init container "sysctl: error setting key 'net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range': Read-only file system"

Tags: kubernetes, containers, sysctl, podsecuritypolicy

I am trying to remove privileged mode from init container, when i set to priviliged: false. I am getting above error. I had set readOnlyRootFilesystem: false and lines below at the pod securityContext level

```
  securityContext:
    sysctls:
    - name: net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
      value: 0 65535
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you cannot run `sysctl` without the privileged mode due to security reasons. This is expected since docker restricts access to `/proc` and `/sys`.

In order for this to work you need to use the privileged mode for the init container and than either:

- [Use sysctls in a Kubernetes Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/) by specifing a proper `securityContext` for a Pod. For example:

---

```
  securityContext:
    sysctls:
    - name: kernel.shm_rmid_forced
      value: "0"
    - name: net.core.somaxconn
      value: "1024"
    - name: kernel.msgmax
      value: "65536"
```

- Use [PodSecurityPolicy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#configure-namespaced-kernel-parameters-sysctls-at-runtime) to control which `sysctls` can be set in pods by specifying lists of `sysctls` or `sysctl` patterns in the `forbiddenSysctls` and/or `allowedUnsafeSysctls` fields of the `PodSecurityPolicy`. For example:

---

```
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
  name: sysctl-psp
spec:
  allowedUnsafeSysctls:
  - kernel.msg*
  forbiddenSysctls:
  - kernel.shm_rmid_forced
```

Notice that:

> If you allow unsafe `sysctls` via the `allowedUnsafeSysctls` field in a
> `PodSecurityPolicy`, any pod using such a `sysctl` will fail to start if
> the `sysctl` is not allowed via the `--allowed-unsafe-sysctls` kubelet
> flag as well on that node.

- You can also set a limited number of `sysctls` on a container-local basis with [`docker run --sysctl`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#configure-namespaced-kernel-parameters-sysctls-at-runtime).

I also recommend going through the whole linked documentation as caution is advised because use of unsafe `sysctls` is at-your-own-risk and can lead to severe problems like wrong behavior of containers, resource shortage or complete breakage of a node.